# Balancing several gateways in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, load-balancing, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

Is there any possibility to create several gateway docker containers with balanced access via the same URL?

I have now the following compose yaml file

```
version: "3.9"

services:
    gateway:
        image: "foo/gateway"
        ports:
            - "8888"
        networks:
            - "my-net"
        deploy:
            replicas: 5
            x-scaling: "4-7"

    factorial:
        image: "foo/factorial"
        expose:
            - "8081"
        networks:
            - "my-net"
        deploy:
            replicas: 3
            x-scaling: "2-4"

    fibonacci:
        image: "foo/fibonacci"
        expose:
            - "8082"
        networks:
            - "my-net"
        deploy:
            replicas: 2
            x-scaling: "1-3"

networks:
    my-net:
        driver: "bridge"
```

[image]

Now I have 3 factorial containers, 2 fibonacci containers, and 5 gateway containers with different ports. Each gateway container has access to some of the factorial/fibonacci replicas, but I need to specify a port of the gateway.

Is there any way to provide one URL to a gateway and have requests balanced between gateway replicas by Docker?

Actually, I'm going to create an ECS cluster with docker-compose and ecs context, but this config doesn't provide me any balancing as I could see.

Answer (score 1):

You can user nginx. Put you backend behind nginx and load balance them in your nginx. Something like below.

```
upstream backend
  {
      server factorial:8001;
      server fibonacci:8002;
  }


location /
    {
      proxy_pass http://backend/;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }
```